# Keeping an icon and a word on the same line in HTML

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I use Font Awesome icons on my site next to links, and I can't figure out how to force the first word of the links to stay on the same line with the icon.

Here's a JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/un5hwhca/

[image: screenshot of the problem at hand]

I'm trying to use `&nbsp;` to keep them together, but it didn't do the trick, as you can see on the screenshot, it just get pushed to the beginning of the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to your link:

```
style="white-space: nowrap;"
```

**[ [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un5hwhca/2/) ]**

Or if you only want the image and the first word to stick together, but let the rest of the link wrap, put the image and the first word in a `span` and apply the style to that one instead, like

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game)" target="_blank">
    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
        some
    </span>
    very interesting Asteroids
</a>
```

**[ [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un5hwhca/4/) ]**

Comment: Is there a way to use this so that the links wrap normally after the first word (so that it only applies to the `&nbsp`, basically)?

Comment: You can wrap the image, `&nbsp`; and the first word in a `span` and apply `style="white-space: nowrap;"` to that one instead... [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un5hwhca/4/)